# Apply scope change in Angular controller using controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
angular
  .module('app.core')
  .controller('TestController', TestController);

TestController.$inject = ['$timeout', '$interval'];

function TestController($timeout, $interval) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.formHeight = '0px';

  $timeout(function() {
    var heightCheck = $interval(function() {
      var formHeightNew = document.getElementById('form').offsetHeight;
      vm.formHeight = formHeightNew + 'px';
    }, 500);
  }, 2000);

};
```

So an interval begins after 2000ms (in the timeout) and then runs every 500ms. It updates the view model with a new value each iteration. The variable in the html view does not seem to update. How do I apply the update?

I've tried adding `vm.$apply()` and injecting $scope and then using `$scope.$apply()` but neither seem to work.

The html simply uses the variable in an `ngStyle` like so (note the controllerAs value is test):

```
<div class="form-wrapper" ng-style="{'height': test.formHeight}">
</div>
```

The initial binding value of '0px' works but the updates do not.

Comment: Post the html code..

Comment: @Max I've updated the question with the HTML now. I don't think there's any issue with that though, because the initial value works, it's the scope updates that have an issue.

Comment: Does test.formHeight change at all?

Comment: Where did you set controllerAs value to  test..? and how will `document.getElementById('form').offsetHeight` keep on changing?

Comment: @TJ The controllerAs value is set to test in the routing config. That part all works fine because the initial scope values display correctly. It's updates within the timeout and interval that do not work. The height of the element in question changes because it's a form in an iframe with validation and is responsive.

Comment: @Coop Maybe you have something else in DOM that alters the scope which you're not showing us?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular
  .module('app.core')
  .controller('TestController', TestController);

TestController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', '$interval'];

function TestController($scope, $timeout, $interval) {

  $scope.formHeight = '0px';

  $timeout(function() {
    var heightCheck = $interval(function() {
      var formHeightNew = document.getElementById('form').offsetHeight;
      $scope.formHeight = formHeightNew + 'px';
    }, 500);
  }, 2000);

};
```

And the html

```
<div class="form-wrapper" ng-style="{'height': formHeight}">
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Also, this doesn't follow the view model syntax. `vm` is the `$scope` so interchanging them shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
This piece of code works properly update every half of second and add new height: 

    <div class="testCtrl" data-ng-controller="appController as test">
        <form action="state1_submit" id="form" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" >
            <input type="text" name="" value="" >
            <div class="form-wrapper" ng-style="{'height': test.formHeight}">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('appController', appController);

function appController($timeout, $interval) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.formHeight = '0px';
    $timeout(function() {
        var heightCheck = $interval(function() {
            var formHeightNew = document.getElementById('form').offsetHeight;
            vm.formHeight = formHeightNew + 'px';
            console.log(vm.formHeight);
            console.log('updat3e');
        }, 500);
    }, 2000);
}
```